Error : SqlException: Invalid column name 'ParentNavbarItemID'. Invalid column name 'ParentNavbarItemID'
NavbarItem.cs
 public class NavBarItems
 {
     public class NavbarAdminViewModel
     {
         public List<ParentNavbarItem> ParentItems { get; set; }
         public List<ChildNavbarItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
         public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
     }

     public class NavbarRoleItem
     {
         public string RoleId { get; set; }
         public string RoleName { get; set; }
     }

     public class ParentNavbarItem
     {
         public string ID { get; set; }
         public string ObjectID { get; set; }
         public string Controller { get; set; }
         public bool IsDropdown { get; set; }
         public string Role { get; set; }
         public int Priority { get; set; }
         public ICollection<ChildNavbarItem> Children { get; set; }
     }

     public class ChildNavbarItem
     {
         public string ID { get; set; }
         public string ObjectID { get; set; }
         public string Controller { get; set; }
         public string Views { get; set; }
         public string Role { get; set; }
     }
 }

ToolController.cs
public async Task<IActionResult> UserAccess()
{
    var viewModel = new NavbarAdminViewModel
    {
        Roles = GetRoles(),
        ParentItems = await _context.WMS_ParentNavbar
            .Include(p => p.Children)
            .ToListAsync(),
        ChildItems = new List<ChildNavbarItem>()
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

UserAccess.cshtml
@model WMS_Frontend.Models.NavBarItems.NavbarAdminViewModel
@using WMS_Frontend.Helpers;

<h1>Navbar Administration</h1>
<p>
    <a asp-action="CreateParentItem">Add New Parent Item</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@RoleHelper.GetRoleName(role.ToString())</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="EditParentItem" asp-route-id="@role">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="DeleteParentItem" asp-route-id="@role">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

RoleHelper.cs
public static class RoleHelper
 {
     public static string GetRoleName(string roleId)
     {
         switch (roleId)
         {
             case "1": return "Administrator";
             case "2": return "Staff";
             case "3": return "Bin Collector";
             case "4": return "Resident";
             default: return "";
         }
     }
 }

Database:
ParentNavbar Table

ChildNavbar Table

Error :

Hello Everyone can someone help with my error. The purpose of this I want to manage this navbar by Administrator this is serve as my UserAccess of the system. I want that the administrator manage this UserAccess. Now I trying to get the details of the parent with corresponding child and display it to the table. But I encountered an error "SqlException: Invalid column name 'ParentNavbarItemID'. Invalid column name 'ParentNavbarItemID'." but i check in the modal i don't have a ParentNavbarItemID im not sure where this column came from.

This error seems to come from EntityFramework's inability to establish relationship between the tables. Show us the EF mappings to figure out why you are getting the error. Secifically the foregin key mappings between the tables.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
